# Java android room Object to map

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have this class :

```
public class RelationshipsOrderAndBins {

    @Embedded
    public RowEntity order;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "order_id", entityColumn = "orderId",entity = LoadingRow.class)
    public List<LoadingRow> bins;
}
```

to get `LiveData<List<RelationshipsOrderAndBins>>` I do this :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN bin ON orders.order_id= bin.orderId")
    LiveData<List<RelationshipsOrderAndBins>> geRelationshipsOrderAndBins();
```

And I have no idea how I can transform to: `HashMap<Integer,List,Loadings>` where key is `order.getId()`

Comment: What do you mean by `HashMap<Integer,List,Loadings>`? `HashMap` only has 2 type parameters, yet you specify 3.

Comment: @JoachimSauer a key is a order.getId() and a this is maping one to many so I get for example  one order and three bins and I want to create a HashMap which a key value is a order.getId() and values is a list of bins

Comment: Do you mean `Map<Integer, List<Loading>>` ? what is that `Loading` object?

Comment: @Bentaye yes a Loading  is my object

Comment: this is not clear at all, there is no `Loading` class in your code. Do you mean `Map<Integer, List<RelationshipsOrderAndBins>>`?

Comment: @Bentaye see this :  public List<LoadingRow> bins

Comment: Well that is `LoadingRow`, not `Loading`.

Comment: @Bentaye in RelationshipsOrderAndBinsi have a list of LoadingRow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200334/discussion-between-kpokrywja-and-bentaye).

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `List` to a `Map`, you can use streams and collect it using `Collectors.toMap`

```
List<RelationshipsOrderAndBins> list = new ArrayList<RelationshipsOrderAndBins>();

Map<Integer, List<LoadingRow>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                r -> r.getOrder().getId(),
                r -> r.getBins()));
```

Comment: and it can be LiveData ?

Comment: I do not know what `LiveData` is, I am not familiar with android-room